# Is there any way to guarantee that the onPause or onStop Android lifecycle events run until the end?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

In the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#activity-lifecycle), it's stated that, at least, `onPause` is not killable. Maybe my interpretation is incorrect but I understood that it would always run until the end. I've made several tests with a lengthy loop cycle and I can interrupt it half call.

I want to save some persistent data in the call but unfortunately, it can be interrupted halfway through. I'm aware I should optimize it and I'm going to do it but I wanted to guarantee that the lifecycle call I'm using would run until the end.

Answer (score 0):

If those events are raised the only way to "brake" them is by throwing an Exception before their end.
Saying that "*onPause/onStop events are not killable*" only means that this below code (pseudo-code) will always execute YOUR CODE:

```
@Override
public void onPause/onStop() {
    try {
        --------------
        YOUR CODE HERE
        --------------
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        super.onPause/onStop();
    }
}
```

However Android Docs says that AFTER these methods the *Process could be killed in any time*, but the onPause/onStop events will be executed from their begin to their end in any case.

If you want to be secure to save persistant data on those ASYNC events, I suggest you to spawn a different Process and pass "serialized" (using AIDL?) objects to it. Obliviously this spawned new Process is reserved to only this kind of execution.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not happening in my example. I created a new project in Android Studio (an AppCompatActivity), I've overridden onPause, added a 20000 iteration loop with logs to it, and returned the superclass at the end, and the logs never finish when I dismiss the app. Also, the onStop event never starts.

Comment: What is written in LogCat in that moment? (in the meanwhile I updated my answer, so please try that solution using TRY..FINALLY block). If it doesn't helps, I suppose you need to do what I wrote at the end of my Answer about spawning a new Process.

Comment: This is the log:


`ActivityManager: kill pid:32001 processName:com.example.myapplication reason:remove task--
ActivityManager: Killing 32001:com.example.myapplication/u0a994 (adj 915): remove task--
TEST    : LOG caught: 20754--
Zygote  : Process 32001 exited due to signal 9 (Killed)--
gwy     : OS Event: appuse--
WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{8554a30 u0 com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}--
libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10994 pid 32001 in 44ms--
ActivityManager: setHasOverlayUi called on unknown pid: 32001`

Comment: The try-catch didn't help

Comment: Is there some ANR (Application Not Responding) message in the log? Because if MainThread/UiThread takes more than (usually) 5seconds the App/Activity could be killed by OS and doing a big loop as you said has a good chance to fall in this case.

Comment: That's pretty acceptable. iOS does something similar but in iOS the lifecycle event runs in the background for 5 seconds after the app is closed. That doesn't happen here.

Sometimes an ANR happens but only when I let the loop run until the end. When I kill it doesn't happen.

Comment: From what I learned in 8 years of Android programming is that on Low Memory/Resources or ANR no anyone can assure a method will not be killed earlier.

Comment: I could understand that if the ANR appeared earlier. If I just send the app to the background, the loop keeps on running without a problem. It's only when I dismiss the app that it stops.